# Veins - INET compatibility

Tags: omnet++, wave, inet, veins

I’m currently searching for 802.11p simulation feasability and I would like to test IPv6 as well, apart from the WAVE/IEE 802.11p. The INET would be the solution but I’m doubting about the compatibility with the Veins 4 alpha 2 (latest version).

What I know is that Veins 3.X was based on MiXiM, but at the same time INET and MiXiM can be compatible and installed together in OmNET, combining them or even with MixNET.

I would really like to know if somebody has achieved them work al together (OmNET + Veins + INET o MiXiM+INET).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of Veins you run:

Later versions of Veins can be used together with INET 3.4.0. The process is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41833646/4707703

Veins 4a2 can be used together with modules from the INET framework version 2.3.0. To allow this, you will need to either run `./configure --with-inet=PATH` (if you build Veins from the command line) or select the corresponding "With INET Framework" project feature (if you build Veins from the IDE).
Note that there is not (yet) a module included in Veins that can connect the INET module modeling the network layer to a Veins module modeling the MAC layer. This will need to be written by you.
Still, for a quick test, you can then add INET modules to your `Scenario` (you probably want `ChannelControl` and `IPv4NetworkConfigurator`) and to your cars (you will probably want your `Car` to extend `AdhocHost`).
This will let you instantiate INET applications on your cars as common in INET, e.g., by configuring

```
**.nodeCount = 2

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 2500m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 2500m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 50m

**.node[*].udpApp[*].sendInterval = uniform(250ms, 750ms)
**.node[*].udpApp[0].startTime = 0ms
**.node[*].wlan[0].**.bitrate = 11Mbps
**.node[*].wlan[0].**.globalARP = true

**.node[*].numUdpApps = 1
**.node[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.node[*].udpApp[0].destAddresses = "224.0.0.1"
**.node[*].udpApp[0].localPort = 1
**.node[*].udpApp[0].destPort = 1
**.node[*].udpApp[0].messageLength = 100B
**.node[*].udpApp[0].joinLocalMulticastGroups = true
```