# veins 4 alpha 2 download

Tags: omnet++, inet, veins, sumo

Good morning everybody,

I'm working on my thesis according to which I should compare results got with both VANET communications (*Veins*) and D2D communications (*simuLTE*). In order to run these simulations I need all the following tools running together.

So, I need to download **veins 4 alpha 2** since I'm going to work with *omnet++ 4.6* and *inet 2.3*, which requires *sumo 0.22* as far as I understood, didn't I?

I was looking for Veins 4 alpha 2 on the website http://veins.car2x.org/download/ and then googling it, but I can find only the changelog and not the download link.

How can I get it?

Thanks in advance
Best regards
FMA

Comment: Newer versions of Veins support linking with newer versions of the INET Framework and of SUMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41833646/4707703

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can always find all older versions of Veins as tags [in the repository on github](https://github.com/sommer/veins).

The version you are looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/archive/veins-4a2.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing from the name this seems to be the right file: http://veins.car2x.org/download/veins-4a2.zip. But why don't you go with the most recent version?

Comment: Is the last version of veins (4.4) compatible with the versions of the other tools that I need and I mentioned before? If it is so, I'll go with the latest version then. thank you

Comment: According to the download page http://veins.car2x.org/download/ it won't needs SUMO version at least 0.25 instead of 0.22 but also a newer SUMO should be better. It should work with Omnet 4.6 but I never tried myself.

Comment: Okay thank you,. So the last question is: which is the most suitable SUMO version for INET v2.3? Since SUMO 0.25 API doesn't fit that simulation returning this kind of error:


<!> Error in module (TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) scenario.manager (id=3) at event #1, t=0: Model error: TraCI server "SUMO 0.25.0" reports API version 10. This server is unsupported..


TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?

Simulation terminated with exit code: 133